# Good library for TCP reassembly

Tags: tcp, stream, wireshark, pcap, snort

What are some good libraries for doing TCP reassembly? I have some pcap files (too large to handle using wireshark) and I want to do TCP reassembly. Development of libnids seems to have stopped. I'm wondering if anybody could give

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151417/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the bro-ids http://bro-ids.org/ TCP layer written in C++? You are able to write simple application layer bro-scripts to do whatever you need to do. Otherwise, you can take a look on their src code.

Comment: I see bro-ids websites.there is not any point to TCP reassembly.