# Tool to monitor/record TCP streams

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I'm trying to analyze JSON-RPC traffic from an application to understand an undocumented protocol. So far, I've been using Wireshark's "follow TCP stream" feature, but there's a lot of clicking involved.

Could I use tcpdump or tshark to accomplish something similar?

I simply need all of the the TCP stream data going from/to a specific host dumped to stdout.

Comment: It's 4 clicks for what you want to do. I don't think you'll find anything more easy and advanced as wireshark.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's JSON-RPC or the particular service I'm looking at, but there seems to be an empty HTTP call every 10 seconds or so, which actually turns into a lot of clicking when I'm waiting on a particular RPC call to come through.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how do you do it but why don't you capture the whole traffic and filter it after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org)'s [contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125544/1170277) script to record the payload of a TCP stream. Just invoke Bro as follows:

```
bro -r trace.pcap contents
```

which will create files in the form of

```
contents.<sourceIP>.<sourcePORT>-<destinationIP>.<destinationPORT>
```

per flow. What you get with Bro is a thoroughly tested TCP reassembler, which makes it the ideal tool for payload inspection and higher-level protocol analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The tool that let me do what I was looking for was "ngrep", I did:

```
sudo ngrep -Wbyline '' dst host <ip-address> or src host <ip-address>
```