# How to see webpage content (as a whole) sent to user with wireshark

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet, packet-capture

I use my pc as the wifi hotspot, and connect other devices to it. Then with wireshark, I can see the packets sending/receiving on a specific device, but how can I see the complete webpage that the device is viewing instead of separate packets?

Answer (score 4):

Try to find packets of HTTP protocol with data. Try filter: `http && (media || data-text-lines)`. And look what you get in this packets.[image]

Comment: thank you. very helpful. Could you further explain how I can transform these codes into a web page?  since there are many 'noise' that aren't html i.e. t\r\n  [truncated] etc..

Comment: Exactly, right-click on 'Line-based text...' line -> 'Export Selected Packet Bytes...' Then you can open it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can not see the web page you can just see the protocol packets.

for detailed information please refer http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html section 7

Comment: I saw it somewhere that you can sort of reassembly the packet to form the web page or image...

Answer (score 0):

As @graphite said, you can save the line to a file.
Your packet capture should also have caught the supporting files such as .css, images, etc; you may need to make placeholder files if you didn't get these.

You may also look at this answer here; the options included seem to more or less address what you're looking for: [Complete reconstruction of TCP Session (HTML pages) from WireShark pcaps, any tools for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151417/complete-reconstruction-of-tcp-session-html-pages-from-wireshark-pcaps-any-to)

I'm kind of surprised I couldn't find some sort of "replay" browser plugin that takes PCAPs and simulates it using IE's DLL or the like...